# Not all items in assets folder get packaged in APK

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android Studio. I packaged up and built an app. Now I'm trying to change whats in my assets folder but some images aren't making it into the APK. I know this because I changed it to a zip extension and extracted but there missing. I've tried the sync project with gradle files and the sync with file system options but there not helping. Obviously there's a step I'm missing here. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your proguard/shrinkResources enabled? Because those missing images must have been deleted while compilation.

Comment: Leave a comment if your gonna down vote.

Comment: Upvoting because this is a legitimate issue I run into often. I have to File > Invalidate Caches before my assets will update, even if I drag them into the Android Studio window directly.

Comment: Upvoting because the comments and the answer below helped a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rebuild Project option ended up doing the trick. I'm still not sure why the sync functions didn't take care of the issue. O well Im sure I'll run into the answer eventually.